# How to implement trait IndexMut for custom Trait when IndexMut requires Index, which is implemented for the supertrait of the custom trait

Tags: rust, traits

Lets say I have this code

```
trait Indexable {
    fn get(&self, index: usize) -> &bool;
}

trait IndexableMut: Indexable {
    fn get_mut(&mut self, index: usize) -> &mut bool;
}

impl Index<usize> for dyn Indexable {
    type Output = bool;
    fn index(&self, index: usize) -> &Self::Output {
        self.get(index)
    }
}
```

is it possible to implement

```
impl IndexMut<usize> for dyn IndexableMut {
    fn index(&mut self, index: usize) -> &mut Self::Output {
        self.get_mut(index)
    }
}
```

without explicitly implementing `Index<usize>` for `IndexableMut`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. `Index<usize>` is a supertrait of `IndexMut<usize>`, so you must implement `Index` if you want to implement `IndexMut`.

The fact that `Indexable` is a supertrait of `IndexableMut` is irrelevant because `dyn Indexable` and `dyn IndexableMut` are still different types. Just because `dyn Indexable` implements `Index<usize>` does not mean that `dyn IndexableMut` does.

Comment: Ok, thanks I couldn't really find anything about this so I thought it might be possible